# mvc [Remote] tag reference separate project controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, entity-framework-6

**first** let me say I think I know my issue, but I don't know how to solve it.
I've been tasked with cleaning up the validation section for our application.
We have entity models and MVC Application in separate projects, one called "core" and the other called "webapp"

I can't seem to get my [Remote] validation to fire. I've done my research, but I believe it's because, I'm trying to reference a controller in my separate project.

**Simplified model in my core project looks something like**

```
namespace Project.Core.Models
{
    [Table(name: "MT_DATABASE_SERVERS")]
    public class DatabaseServer : ModelBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        [Display(Name = "Database Server")]
        [Remote("IsPropertyExists","DatabaseServers", HttpMethod = "POST",ErrorMessage = "This Server is already in use.")]
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**and here is a simplified controller logic**

```
namespace Project.WebApp.Controllers.Servers
{
    public class DatabaseServersController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DatabaseServer databaseServer
        {
            using (var db = GetMTContext()) 
            {
                db.DatabaseServers.Add(databaseServer);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult IsPropertyExists(string property)
        {
            using (var db = GetMTContext())
            {
                return Json(!db.DatabaseServers.Any(x => x.ServerName == property), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In developer tools of your browser do you see and XHR request sent by your browser? If yest, what is the status code?

Comment: yes, all with status 200. I'm not sure what I'm looking for in particular. I see xmlHttpRequests. at the top of the list I have a POST for create view. then the next one is a GET for the List view I'm assuming is for the redirect after db update.

Comment: Your property name is `ServerName `, therefore the method must be `public ActionResult IsPropertyExists(string ServerName)` - they must match

Comment: I tried that but still didn't register anything. :/

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify `AdditionalFields = "property"` then your code like

```
 [Remote("IsPropertyExists","DatabaseServers", AdditionalFields = "property", HttpMethod = "POST",ErrorMessage = "This Server is already in use.")]
    public string ServerName { get; set;a  }
```

But the condition is you need to add or exist additional field `property`  in your model or entity.

Comment: this did not change anything. how can I specify the right controller "DatabaseServers" if that controller exists in a different project? I believe that is my issue.

Comment: you looking different project controller means it's in the same solution?

Comment: same solution. different projects. see the namespaces to get an idea of how the solution looks

Comment: for clarity....my Web App project depends on my Core project (core is our data model). I can't add a dependency to Webapp since WebApp already references Core project.